# normalizing training data so that it has a mean of 0 and a range between -0.5 and 0.5

Tags: python, training-data

Trying to normalize the input data which a matrix of images in to a mean of 0 and a range of -0.5 and 0.5 in python

```
def normalise(image):
    return 0.1 + (((image_data-0)*(0.9-0.1))/(255 - 0))
```

Was trying to use min-max scaling, but wrong answer I get close to 0.1 for min and max

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range

Comment: My intuition is that this is not possible unless the distribution of your data is symmetric. If it is, then just demean it first and then scale it.
x' = x-mean(x) and
x'' = -0.5 + (x'+0.5)/(max(x')-min(x'))

Comment: @TobiasR Likely, the term range is being used informally.

Comment: Would this be better: " you've loaded the training data, normalize the input so that it has a mean of 0 and a range between -0.5 and 0.5.", sorry if I am not expressing myself well.

Comment: Exactly. I think this is not possible. If you demean it and then normalize the range then the mean will no longer be zero unless the distribution of the data is symmetric around the mean. Let's say your data is 1,2,6. You demean it, then you get -2, -1, 3. Scale it to go from -0.5 to 0.5 you get -0.5, -0.1, 0.5, which has mean -0.0333...

Of course you can still change your data in a way that makes the range -0.5 to 0.5 and the mean zero, but this will affect other moments of the data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want scaling.  Here is example:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

data = np.array([70, -5, 5, 3, 2, 1])
scale = preprocessing.minmax_scale(data, feature_range=(-0.5, 0.5))
print scale
```

out:

```
[ 0.5        -0.5        -0.36666667 -0.39333333 -0.40666667 -0.42      ]
```

Comment: This does not have mean zero. What OP is asking is not possible in general.

Comment: @TobiasR That is true, but his data could be a sin wave.  I did not see any sample posted :)

Comment: This seems quite right, but I may have to reshape my matrix as its shape is (39209, 32, 32, 3) and i get  "Found array with dim 4. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2"

Comment: @kevbuntu you would need to do each column individually - Not sure if this is specifically what you are looking for as it wont give you a mean of 0.

Comment: My original code " 0.1 + (((image_data-0)*(0.9-0.1))/(255 - 0))" gives a mean of 0 but not a data set between -0.5 and 0.5. I was thinking of running it on the column only !?

Comment: @kevbuntu ah well, you can try getting the mean to 0 and then try this :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a special case of "normalization".
normalization will scale your data fram -1 to 1. And then you can divide all of your items by 2.
You want to scale you variable from -0.5 to 0.5.
Then what you can do is :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
c = normalize(yourData)/2
```

For example, `normalize([1,2,3,5, -5, 0,6])/2` will give :

```
[[ 0.3   0.   -0.25  0.25  0.15  0.1   0.05]]
```

Comment: The problem is the shape of my matrix (39209, 32, 32, 3)

Comment: Also how does your data is normalized between -0.5 and 0.5 without declaring it as a range?

Comment: Normalisation scale your data to [-1,1]. You can read the doc of normalization. the thing is, that doesn't put your mean at 0. you may need to substract your mean : `c = c - np.mean(c)`

Answer (score 1):

thankyou, both your answers are correct and lead me to the right place, but I had to deal with the first column so this worked out best for me

```
def normalize(X):
max=0.5
min=-0.5
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
return X_scaled
```

Though the mean is not exactly is but the assert code round() it, so it  becomes zero